# Google does not index breadcrumb navigation

Tags: search, indexing, seo, breadcrumbs

I would like to ask for help.
5 months ago, I added this code on my web:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://myweb.com",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement":
    [
    {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item":
    {
    "@id": "http://myweb.com",
    "name": "Myweb"
    }
    }
                ,{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item":
        {
        "@id": "http://myweb.com/adverts/cars",
        "name": "Cars"
        }
        }
                    ]
    }
</script>
```

But Google is still not showing breadcrumb navigation by results on my web. Where am I wrong?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL on @context to be http://schema.org so that it looks as below

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
"itemListElement":
[
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 1,
"item":
{
"@id": "http://myweb.com",
"name": "Myweb"
}
}
            ,{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item":
    {
    "@id": "http://myweb.com/adverts/cars",
    "name": "Cars"
    }
    }
                ]
}
```

Then validate it using Google's tool https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: That's part of the markup. It's not a variable that needs to change for every site. More information on the implementation of JSON for breadcrumbs schema markup is available here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs?hl=en